# MSVS Linker doesn't find symbol

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, unresolved-external

I am having trouble with the Linker in VS2022.
Basically I have a class, some functions in a "raw" file and some functions in a namespace. There is a small description (non exhaustive)

Embree (static lib)

- API.h
- Embree.h (with getIntersection_RayHit declaration)
- API.cpp
- Embree.cpp (with getIntersection_RayHit definition)

LibEmbree (static lib)

- LibEmbree.h
- LibEmbree.cpp

TestLibEmbree (executable)

- TestLibEmbree.cpp (needs both libraries)

When building the project, I have the following error (there is actually a lot more errors, for a few different functions) :

```
1>TestLibEmbree.obj : error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu "struct RayHit __cdecl getIntersection_RayHit(struct RTCSceneTy * const,float const *,float const *)" (?getIntersection_RayHit@@YA?AURayHit@@QEAURTCSceneTy@@PEBM1@Z) référencé dans la fonction "void __cdecl testPhil3(void)" (?testPhil3@@YAXXZ)
```

However intellisense is auto-completing for those functions and I have no problems (nothing underlined or red) when coding.

I saw a lot of similar issues on this platform but none of the fixes I tried actually fixed the problem. This is possibly a duplicate however none of the other questions I found were actually similar (not the same configuration or version of MSVS). I believe I do have the right #include for the "TestLibEmbree" file (that contains testPhil3), for example :

> #include "../Embree/Embree.h"

Do any of you have an idea to solve this issue ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Well where is: `struct RayHit __cdecl getIntersection_RayHit(struct RTCSceneTy * const,float const *,float const *)` implemented?

Comment: `#include "../Embree/Embree.h"`  is not the solution to a linker error. The solution is likely adding the library to `Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies` if this function is implemented.

Comment: ***However intellisense is auto-completing for those functions and I have no problems (nothing underlined or red) when coding.*** Intellisense does not detect linker errors.

Comment: ***found were actually similar (not the same configuration or version of MSVS)*** Neither of these should matter. Linking is the same.

Comment: Does `TestLibEmbree` link to both libraries and not just `LibEmbree`?

Comment: Yes the function is implemented, in the file Embree.cpp (I will add more detail to my question, I believe I wasn't very clear. And yes, TestLibEmbree needs the two libraries.
Why is there no problem with LibEmbree not being there, but Embree requires it ? Everything was working fine before I added the new Embree library to the solution.

Comment: I added "Embree.lib" and "LibEmbree.lib" to TestLibEmbree Additional Dependencies, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: You may want to try to run `dumpbin /symbols Embree.lib` and see  if `?getIntersection_RayHit@@YA?AURayHit@@QEAURTCSceneTy@@PEBM1@Z` is in the output.

Comment: That doesn't seem to do anything, however using `dumpbin -linkermember .\Embree.lib` I found the following line : `2EB2 ?getIntersection_RayHit@@YA?AURayHit@@QEAURTCSceneTy@@PEBM1@Z`

Comment: Hi, glad to know your problem has been solved! Please consider accepting it  to change its status to Answered.  It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to solve my problem. I don't really know why for some of my libraries it is not needed.

Go to your project properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies and add the **full path** to the .lib (usually in the x64/Release or /debug folder).

And then, magically, it works.

Comment: With Visual Studio a header file can contain a #pragma telling the linker what library it should link. Then it might magically just work.

Comment: So you did not have an error about can not open `Embree.lib`. I would expect this error along with the linker error. If not perhaps you have more than 1 `Embree.lib` file in different folders??